# Sharing buttons and logic across views and controllers

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application

I'm working on a single page app that behaves similar to a wizard.  The user lands on page 1 and needs to save and continue to get to page 2.  What's the best way to share those buttons between all the views?  My form names are different so I currently have to duplicate these buttons so I can use logic like:

```
<div class="mySaveButton" ng-disabled="page1Form.$invalid"></div>
```

but then on page 2:

```
<div class="mySaveButton" ng-disabled="page2Form.$invalid"></div>
```

To further complicate matters, saving on page1 posts the data to a different address than page2.  I have a navigation controller which is the parent and that needs to be handled as well.

So to summarize I need my buttons (`Back`, `Save` and `Save and Continue`) to do all of the following without having to duplicate the buttons across all views:

- Check if the current form is valid
- If it's valid, the data for that form needs to post to the correct endpoint for that form
- Navigation needs to be notified so that it can update and/or take action

Comment: You may what to look at commangular for this functionality http://commangular.org/

Comment: As Rob sail, I use commangular for a signup process that requires registration, verification of mobile et al.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you need to re-use a template (/controller), and somehow pass options into it. You could probably do something with `ngInclude` and nesting controllers, but a way that is more friendly to more complex structure later is to create a custom directive. It depends a bit on your exact use-case, and exactly what you need to pass into it, but a simple version would be something like:

```
app.directive('formButtons', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      'localBack':'&back',
      'localSave':'&save',
      'localSaveAndContinue':'&saveAndContinue'
    },
    templateUrl: 'buttons.html'
  };
});
```

With a template of

```
<div>
  <button ng-click="localBack()">Back</button>
  <button ng-click="localSave()">Save</button>
  <button ng-click="localSaveAndContinue()">Save &amp; Continue</button>
</div>
```

The scope options with `&` each define a function on the directive's scope, that evaluates contents of the attribute on the `<form-buttons>` element of that name in the parent scope. You can then use the directive as follows

```
<form-buttons back="back(2)" save="save(2)" save-and-continue="saveAndContinue(2)"></form-buttons>
```

which will get replaced by the template of the directive, and the function `save`, `back` and `saveAndContinue`, which are defined on the parent scope, will get called when clicking on the buttons in the template, passing the appropriate step number which can be used to customise behaviour.

You can see a working example at http://plnkr.co/edit/fqXowQNYwjQWIbl6A5Vy?p=preview